# Spring boot - user didn't receive a response body if response status is 500/503

Tags: json, spring-boot, controller, response

I'm new in Spring Boot and faced with strange behavior on it.
When I send ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(serviceTestResult) from my controller - user receives responce with my text in data.

```
{data: Array(1), status: 400, config: {…}, statusText: "", headers: ƒ, …}
config: {method: "POST", transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), jsonpCallbackParam: "callback", paramSerializer: ƒ, …}
----> data: ["FIND ME!!!"] <------
headers: ƒ (d)
status: 400
statusText: ""
xhrStatus: "complete"
__proto__: Object
```

But if I send ResponseEntity.status(500).body(serviceTestResult) than user receives "**error: 500 null**"

```
{data: {…}, status: 500, config: {…}, statusText: "", headers: ƒ, …}
config: {method: "POST", transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), jsonpCallbackParam: "callback", paramSerializer: ƒ, …}
----> data: {error: "500 null"} <----
headers: ƒ (d)
status: 500
statusText: ""
xhrStatus: "complete"
__proto__: Object
enter code here
```

My code:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RepositoryRestController
public class MyController {
 @PostMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> test(@RequestBody Object src) {
    List<String> serviceTestResult = new ArrayList<>();
    serviceTestResult.add("FIND ME!!!");
    return ResponseEntity.status(500).body(serviceTestResult);
    }
}
```

Could you please give me advice on how I can send correct data or why it can't be done?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tested the same code as in your question, and its working as expected, it gives body as ["FIND ME!!!"] with 500 HTTP code, I suspect that there might be some conversion done by your web server before providing the body back to the client.

Comment: Are you running this locally on tomcat?

Comment: nothing wrong,try to find out if you have some post processor of the result ,which can be annotationed by @ResponseAdvice to intercept the result